# Error : Cannot read property 'getAuthInstance' of undefined while using login in with google IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-signin, capacitor

I am seeing this error while integrating signin with google in ionic using angular by referring the link given below.

Referred link: https://devdactic.com/capacitor-google-sign-in/

ERROR:
[image]

I have tried debugging the issue and trying to search it in google but didn't find any relevant docs.

Code :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  userInfo = null;
 
  constructor() { }
 
  async googleSignup() {
    const googleUser = await Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn(null) as any;
    console.log('my user: ', googleUser);
    this.userInfo = googleUser;
  }
}
```

And I would like to know is there any alternative for **Plugins** which is deprecated in @capactior/core

Comment: After doing few changes related to imports in capacitor 3, I still see same issue but when i try doing the same signin operation it is working fine. In short, I see this issue only for the first time. Do suggest if i miss anything

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this for a while, the proposed solutions didn't work for me but the following code did:

> home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleAuth} from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';
import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'home.page.scss' ],
})
export class HomePage {
  userInfo = null;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
      GoogleAuth.init();
    });
  }

  async googleSignup() {
    const googleUser = await GoogleAuth.signIn() as any;
    console.log('my user: ', googleUser);
    this.userInfo = googleUser;
  }
}
```

Then call the googleSignup from the `home.page.html` :

```
<ion-button (click)="googleSignup()">Sign in</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you miss this point in migration Capacitor 2 -> Capacitor 3:
https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth#migration-guide

And your code should looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleAuth } from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    userInfo = null;

    constructor() { }

    async googleSignup() {
        GoogleAuth.init(); // or await GoogleAuth.init()
        const googleUser = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
        console.log('my user: ', googleUser);
        this.userInfo = googleUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried changes which you suggested. Still same error ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthInstance' of undefined. And both capactior cli and core versions are same which is 3.1.1

Comment: @Jakkarohith Did you set the client id?

Comment: Yes i did. I have set the client ID

Comment: @Jakkarohith Which platform do you use for testing?

Comment: Browser and also once it is working in browser i thought of building and try testing it in android

Comment: @Jakkarohith Oh... I don't know should it works on the web or not. Capacitor plugins work mainly for mobile platforms (Android and iOS). Try to test it on the mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to fix it after going through the plugin code.

The problem is @codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth 3.0.2 still uses capacitor.config.json while Capacitor 3+ is using capacitor.config.ts.
So I just added the old capacitor.config.json and now it works for me.
There is already an issue opened for the Capacitor team and I hope they will fix it soon.